# Is it common practice to use transformers rated 50% over the load you want to use?

Tags: power-supply, transformer

I designed a flyback power converter circuit with a transformer rated for 25 Watts, I expect to use all 25 Watts, could I use a transformer rated for 35 watts in this application?

Is this typically like a "18 watt power supply" because it does have some room to go over but its guaranteed at 18?

Comment: Flyback transformer power rating is not normally specified because it is dependent on switching frequency. Please link to the device in question.

Comment: Without the switching frequency and details of the HF transformer in question, your answer is incomplete (at best) and potentially incorrect.  Yes, you want to avoid \$I_{pk}\$ and \$I_{sat}\$ by a good margin, but these are not the only factors to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer "Select a transformer that has a peak primary current (Ipk) or primary saturation current (Isat) that is well above the expected primary current peak for your application"

https://www.coilcraft.com/edu/flyback_transformer.cfm

Comment: That doesn't explicitly define the power because power throughput is also a function of switching frequency - didn't you read my earlier comment? The answer you have given is therefore unsatisfactory. Link to a transformer.

Comment: My question is about load

Comment: Load power requirements is one thing but flyback transformers are not specifically defined in terms of load power. You are missing the point. PLEASE LINK TO A DEVICE so this can be explained to you and our time isn't wasted further.

Comment: you missed MY point on MY question